# Sheets Apps Script messages not showing on shared sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a Google Sheet with apps script functions to convert and load data into a spreadsheet.  I have tested it on my own account and all of the functionality works correctly.  I have shared the spreadsheet with another user to test and use it.  It functions as expected other than one point, none of the msgBox or toast messages show while the other user is using the shared sheet.  Is there a setting that I am missing?

Here is my script to convert, load the data and issue messages to the user:

```js
function uploadCMS(e){
  //function to upload CMS .csv data into spreadsheet.  Load into membership directory, then loads spreadsheet.
  let start = new Date()
  console.log(e)
  
  //copy CMS .csv file to membership directory, for historical use
  var CMSFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(CMSFileDirectory).createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e))
  //parse .csv file
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(CMSFile.getBlob().getDataAsString());

  //check for valid file
  if (csvData[0][0] != 'Member Number') {
    //first field of first line tested for BSAC file format to check valid CMS file
    Browser.msgBox("This does not look like a BSAC CMS file, did you select the correct file?")
    return
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CMS data');
  //delete rows from previous downloads
  sheet.deleteRows(1,sheet.getLastRow() - 1)
  //put data in sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, csvData[0].length).setFontWeight("bold");
  //create named range for CMS data to use in spreadsheet lookups/queries
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, csvData.length - 1, csvData[0].length);
  var worksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  worksheet.setNamedRange("CMSRange", range);
  
  let ConfMessage = "CMS .csv file loaded successfully.  " + String(csvData.length - 1) + " records loaded."
  //Browser.msgBox(ConfMessage)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(ConfMessage);

  let end = new Date()
  console.log((end - start)/1000 + "s")
}
```

The script is called from a menu item which initiates a sidebar for file selection which is set-up thus:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Load')
      .addItem('levy data', 'openLevySidebar')
      .addItem('CMS data', 'openCMSSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

const openLevySidebar = _ => SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("levy"));
const openCMSSidebar = _ => SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("CMS"));
```

The HTML for the sidebar is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <a>Select a BSAC CMS .csv download file<br><br></a>
  <form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="uploadCMS(this.parentNode)" accept=".csv" />
</form>
<script>
function uploadCMS(e){
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = e => google.script.run.uploadCMS([[...new Int8Array(e.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
</html>
```

When I am signed in to my own profile and access the sheet from my own Gdrive, I can select a file, run the load and get success or error messages.

[image]

When I am signed in to my profile, but access the sheet which I have shared with a another user, but using their Gdrive, the script runs but no success or error messages are shown.

[image]

The other user has editor access via Google file sharing.
The Apps Script is part of a GCP project.  The other user is a named owner of that project.
I have deployed the script and the web app can be used by anyone.

Comment: About `It functions as expected other than one point, none of the msgBox or toast messages show while the other user is using the shared sheet.`, in this case, I think that it is required to know the method for correctly replicating it. So, can you provide the details flow for correctly replicating your situation including your current script? Although this is just my guess, if your script is run with the simple trigger, please change it to the installable trigger. But, I'm not sure your situation. This is just my guess. I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the question text with as much information as I am aware of.  Regarding triggers, the app has none.  It is executed from a sheet when the user selects a file to process.

Comment: I think it has something to do with profiles and accounts.  When I have the sheet open with the same profile and account, it works fine.  However when the profile is different to the account, the msgBox does not show.  The latter situation exists when I test - I am in my profile, but use the other user's account to access the sheet on their account's Gdrive.  When I do this and run the script, the messages do not show.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your current script. About `Regarding triggers, the app has none.`, when I saw your script, what is `e` of `function uploadCMS(e){`? How do you run your function? Can you provide the details flow for correctly replicating your situation including the whole script?

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this.  Original message updated with more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I am signed in to my profile, but access the sheet which I have shared with a another user, but using their Gdrive, the script runs but no success or error messages are shown.`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: Your english is fine, I apologise for not being able to articulate my problem clearly!  I am accessing the sheet using Chrome.  I have multiple profiles (one personal and one "business".)  I sign-in to Chrome with my personal account (e.g. all bookmarks are synchronised).  I then open a tab containing the spreadsheet on my  Gdrive  (first picture above).  If I close this, open a tab for my business account Gdrive, I see the shared spreadsheet there, I open it (2nd picture above), spreadsheet opens, appears to work fine but I am not alerted by messages created by the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although in your question, you don't say about the value of `CMSFileDirectory`, from your reply, in your situation, if the folder of folder ID `CMSFileDirectory` is not shared with the user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet, an error occurs at `var CMSFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(CMSFileDirectory).createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e))`. I'm worried about it. How about this? But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, I post it as a comment. If my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, I checked and all the folders which the scrip uses are shared (editor) with the users who will execute the script.  Sorry, I didn't share as the folder contains sensitive information.